# os.urandom or ssl.RAND_bytes?

Tags: python

[os.urandom](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.urandom) or [ssl.RAND_bytes](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ssl.html#ssl.RAND_bytes): when generating random bytes for cryptographic purposes, which is more recommended?

If neither one is better, what are the tradeoffs and what is to be expected from each in terms of differences?

Note that ssl.RAND_bytes only exists in Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssl.RAND_bytes` needs to be seeded before it can be used. So you cannot just rely on `ssl.RAND_bytes` alone. Both `os.urandom` and `` `ssl.RAND_bytes `` are *pseudo* random number generators. PRNG's are deterministic; when seeded with the same data, they will return the same stream of pseudo random number bytes. These bytes should be indistinguishable from true random if an observer does not know the seed value. `os.urandom` however is normally (re-)seeded using a source of entropy within the operating system.

Using `os.urandom` should therefore be preferred over `ssl.RAND_bytes`. First of all, it is already seeded (and will be reseeded by the operating system). Furthermore, it does not require an additional dependency on an SSL library. A drawback could be performance. It is probably faster to use `ssl.RAND_bytes` seeded with a big enough value from `os.urandom` as `os.urandom` requires a system call any time you retrieve data.

Comment: Note: I'm not a python developer, this is extracted from the information found from the links you pointed to.